# I'm trying to write a game in python with turtle graphics, but the movement's broken

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So, this is what I have so far:

```
import time
import random

#Window
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Turtle Game")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#Player's character
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.speed(0)
player.shape("square")
player.color("white")
player.penup()
player.goto(0,0)
player.direction = "stop"

#Player's movement
def go_up():
    if player.direction != "down":
        player.direction = "up"

def go_down():
    if player.direction != "up":
        player.direction = "down"

def go_left():
    if player.direction != "right":
        player.direction = "left"

def go_right():
    if player.direction != "left":
        player.direction = "right"

def move():
    if player.direction == "up":
        y = player.ycor()
        player.sety(y + 20)

    if player.direction == "down":
        y = player.ycor()
        player.sety(y - 20)

    if player.direction == "left":
        x = player.xcor()
        player.setx(x - 20)

    if player.direction == "right":
        x = player.xcor()
        player.setx(x + 20)

#Listen for keypresses
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")
```

At the moment, all I'm getting is a blank screen in the window. the #Window seems to work fine, but other than that, nothing else is appearing. I'm honestly not sure why this is happening, so I've turned to StackOverflow for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some points on your code:

1. I had to add `import turtle` at the beginning, to use the `turtle` module.
2. The window opened and then closed immediately. I had to add `wn.exitonclick()` at the end to keep the window open.
3. The `move()` function is never called. I had to add a call to `move()` in each of `go_up`, `go_down`, `go_left` and `go_right` after the player direction is updated.
4. You disable tracing by setting `wn.tracer(0)`. Following the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.tracer), without tracing you have to refresh the window manually using `turtle.update()`. I added this call to the end of the `move()` function. Alternativaly, you could use `wn.tracer(1)` to automatically refresh the screen on every change.

   Admittedly the documentation is not perfectly clear on the effect of `0`.

Applying these changes to your code gives me a window where I can move around the turtle using <kbd>w</kbd>/<kbd>a</kbd>/<kbd>s</kbd>/<kbd>d</kbd>.

One additional note: It is unclear to me what you are trying to do with the `if` statements in your `go_`... functions. In `go_up()`, you set the direction to `up` only if it is not currently `down`. This has the effect that when I moved the turtle down, I cannot move it up again until I make a side-step via `go_left()`/`go_right()`. This seems strange. Maybe you meant to only update to `up` if the direction is not already `up`? As in:

```
    if player.direction != "up":
        player.direction = "up"
```